# Importing QGIS file in Eclipse for Android application?

Tags: qgis-2, android, eclipse

Using ECLIPSE for android development, and also QGIS for customizing maps, I want to know if I can import the data in QGIS into my android application so that the data of my android applcation will be based on QGIS?

In other words, I want to have one database beneath both my QGIS and android applications.